# Populate two select box from a select box

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, populate

I went through these topics for a solution to my problem but I think my question is a bit different.

- [Using javascript and jquery, to populate related select boxes with array structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180451/using-javascript-and-jquery-to-populate-related-select-boxes-with-array-structur)
- [Populating a 2nd select box - binding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255992/populating-a-2nd-select-box-binding-problem)

I have 3 select boxes in my form. Named 'Category', 'Subcategory', 'Topic'.

Subcategory is populated from selection of Category and topic is selected from subcategory select box.

I have created a generalized function for populating select boxes using jQuery.

I am calling that function (`populateSelectBox`) on the change event of parent select box.

Now the Subcategory select box is easily populated on the change event of Category select box but **if the subcategory has only one option populated through ajax, the change event for subcategory is not fired as there is only one item in the subcategory select box.**

What shall I do in that case in?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test for the number of options received and if there's only one, trigger the `change` event manually:

```
$('#mySubCategorySelect').trigger('change');
```

or just:

```
$('#mySubCategorySelect').change();
```

Another way to go would be to have an `option` at the top of each `select` that is effectively a heading. Something like:

```
<select>
    <option>Please choose a category</option>
    <option>some option</option>
</select>
```

This would require the user to choose an option, even if only one exists.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer as I needed to populate the third select box only on the change event of second select box.

**Thanks to patrick for giving an idea of blank select option**

So instead of adding an empty 'select option' through PHP, I modified my populateSelectBox function in such a way that it will **automatically add a blank 'select' option to the response**, like this `$element.append('<option value="">Select</option>');` so that change event can be triggered by the user.