# Populate a <select></select> box with another

Tags: html, ajax

```
<select name="class">

  <option>  --select class--  </option>

</select>

<select name="subject">

  <option> --select subject-- </option>

</select>
```

now i want to use the ajax to populate the subject  list box.. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: yes i am using javascipt

Comment: I hope I get you right (in a question I usually expect at least one questionmark), but this might be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255992/populating-a-2nd-select-box-binding-problem

Comment: @Quasdunk: he's not using jquery

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to the change event of the first select box and then trigger an ajax request to your server by passing the selected value. Then in the success callback of this request you could use the JSON array returned by the server to update the contents of the second select box. Here's an example of how to achieve this using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.class').change(function() {
        // when the value of the first select changes trigger an ajax request
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON('/script.cgi', { selectedValue: value }, function(result) {
            // assuming the server returned json update the contents of the 
            // second selectbox
            var subject = $('.subject');
            subject.empty();
            $.each(result, function(index, item) {
                result.append(
                    $('<option/>', {
                        value: item.value
                        text: item.text
                    })
                );
            });
        });
    });
});
```

and the JSON returned from the server could look like this:

```
[ { value: '1', text: 'subject 1' }, { value: '2', text: 'subject 2' } ]
```